# WPF WindowChrome ContentPresenter does not display content

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, window-chrome

When I try to display content from the `ContentPresenter` I cannot see anything. The test block does not display any text and it seems to be hidden.

```
<local:ResizableVideoHostWindow x:Class="TestClass"
        x:ClassModifier="internal"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding Title}">

    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ResizableVideoHostWindow}">
            <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <shell:WindowChrome
                        CaptionHeight="30"
                        CornerRadius="1"
                        GlassFrameThickness="0,0,0,-1"
                        NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                        ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                        UseAeroCaptionButtons="true"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ResizableVideoHostWindow}">
                        <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Button
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    Visibility="Visible"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Width="20"
                                    Height="20"
                                    Margin="8,2,0,0"
                                    shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">

                                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE72B;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
                                    </TextBlock>
                            </Button>

                                <TextBlock
                                    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Height="20"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    TextAlignment="Center" 
                                    Margin="35,4,0,0"
                                    Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" />

                                <Button
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    Visibility="Visible"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="0,0,160,0"
                                    Width="30"
                                    Height="30"
                                    shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">

                                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE712;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
                                    </TextBlock>
                            </Button>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="7" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>

    <Grid Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock Text="Test Block" FontSize="20" >
        </TextBlock>

        <local:AppProxyContainer
            DataContext="{Binding ContainerViewModel}" />
    </Grid> 

</local:ResizableVideoHostWindow>
```

I am mainly confused on how to display the content. I have seen other posts stating that this method of using `ContentPresenter` works, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `ContentPresenter` correctly, but you do not set its column in the `Grid`, so it will be placed in the `LeftPaddingColumn` column, which has zero `Width`.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
   <ColumnDefinition/>
   <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Set its attached `Grid.Column` property to `1`, so it will be displayed in the second column, which sizes to the remaining space.

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```